It doesn't register the value that I give it
It just gives me 2.5 as an answer whenever I input the num and I don't know why, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
#include <stdio.h>
double equ(double num);

int main()
{
        double num;
        double * pnum = &num;
        printf("Give me a number from 1-10: \n");
        scanf("%f", num);
        printf("%f \n%p \n", equ(num), &pnum);
        char sign = ',';
        char characterName1[20];
        char characterName2[]="Alfred";
        printf("Give me a name: ");
        scanf("%s", characterName1);
        printf("-Good day %s\n", characterName1);
        printf("-Good day to you too%c %s", sign, characterName2);
        return 0;
}
double equ(double num){
        double result;
        if(num<5){
                result = (5 + num)/2;
                } else {
                    result = 5 + num;
                }
        return result;
}


This statement scanf("%f", num); invokes undefined behavior. At least you should write scanf("%lf", &num);

The problem was & in front of num(I just forgot to switch the lf since I was testing stuff) but thank you!!!!

No at all. We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Relaxe https://dzen.ru/video/watch/64a86d9dec43747a7a7f4178?from_site=mail :)

If it weren’t you, Vlad, I wouldn’t click random URLs. But I get no sound. ☹️

@Dúthomhas Click the third button below the image to switch on the sound.:)

@VladfromMoscow Dag nab it. That was pretty obvious.

if your compiler didn't complain about not providing an address to scanf, you need to turn up warning level. For gcc use options -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

A couple of things:

You already got that scanf() requires a pointer to the object being stored.
Make sure that scanf() specifies a width for string inputs.
Style issue: stick functions before main().
Style issue: be consistent with braces { } and indentation.
Crank up your compiler warnings as high as you can and fix anything it complains about.

#include <stdio.h>

double equ(double num){
        double result;
        if(num<5){
                result = (5 + num)/2;
        }else{ 
                result = 5 + num;
        }
        return result;
}

int main(void){
        double num;
        double * pnum = &num;
        printf("Give me a number from 1-10: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &num);  // scanf() requires pointer to num
        printf("%f \n%p \n", equ(num), pnum); // pnum is a pointer (== &num)
        char sign = ',';
        char characterName1[20];
        char characterName2[]="Alfred";
        printf("Give me a name: ");
        scanf("%19s", characterName1); // specify maximum string input space (-1 for the terminating nul)
        printf("-Good day %s\n", characterName1);
        printf("-Good day to you too%c %s\n", sign, characterName2); // newline!
        return 0;
}

Some final thoughts:
Notice that pnum is equivalent to &num in all your code.
Using scanf() to obtain user input is iffy. You should generally use fgets() and then parse stuff out (with, say, strtol(), etc).
The maximum string length is important to prevent input buffer overflows. For example, if the user inputs the (English) alphabet as his or her name, the above code will properly stop scanning after “s“ because that is 19 characters (+1 for the terminating nul) means your 20-character string is completely used up as: “abcdefghijklmnopqrs”.
Notice also that if you answer with a name like “Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo” that you’ll only get “Bobobo-bo”, since scanf() stops scanning strings at the first whitespace.

The function equ can be written simpler double equ(double num){
return num < 5 ? (5 + num)/2 : 5 + num;
}

Meh, it’s fine. OP will get there eventually.

First of all thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. Second, I use Code Blocks so I don't know how to exactly do that...

@Nksho27 https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-warning-and-error-levels/ should help.

I even forgot to specify what problem I was having but it was the warning level so thanks for the help
